how to ingest logs from Databricks(GCP) to Azure Log Analytics
we are working on a multicloud architecture where all services will be running on GCP and analytics and logs will be stored on Azure. For this we need to ingest logs to log analytics, how can we do it from GCP databricks in async way.
is there a solution like spark-monitoring for GCP databricks, if not how can we create it?
**Here are things we tried:
**

Earlier we used spark-monitoring library for azure databricks.
We developed a utility to ingest logs via workspace url but this is causing a delay in running jobs.

